# Choosing Between Ruby and Python for a FS Microservice Backend in Node App

Tags: python, ruby, microservices, flask, sinatra

I have been working on a application that up until now has been pure Node.  However I am concerned about performance and overhead since the application performs a lot of file system operations (Copy directory, file writes, Remove Directory, zip....)

Everything works like a charm, but I am thinking it would be best to move the file system operations to a RESTful Microservice since synchronous operations is not what Node is really about.

I believe my options are:

- Python Flask (I have some experience with Python)
- Ruby Sinatra (More experience than Python)
- Keep it in Node.

Does anyone else have some experiences or metrics that can share or general advice to dispense?

Comment: Microservices have some pretty expensive costs associated with them. If I were you, I would keep everything in one app until I proved for sure that I had scalability issues.

Comment: I would prefer to be proactive.    I know Node has certain use cases where it works well, but synchronous/blocking IO operations isn't one of them.